# Segmentation fault using array of promises

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, future

I've written multithreading program, using promises and futures to check whether given number is prime. The correctness or efficiency of this program is not a point, but fact of the segmentation error which occurs in every execution - I had similar problem with more complex program, so I've written this simple one to understand it, and the error is still here. Maybe I don't understand something about concurrency, or promises/futures, but I think that everything is done here in proper way... Can anybody explain why it's not working? It would be very helpful :)

Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>


namespace {
const int THREADS_NUMBER = 8;

void f(int n, std::vector<int>& divisiors, std::promise<bool>& isPossiblePrime) {
    bool isPrimeCandidate = true;
    for (auto i : divisiors)
        if (n % i == 0) {
            isPrimeCandidate = false;
            break;
        }
    isPossiblePrime.set_value(isPrimeCandidate);
}


}

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    assert(n > 2);
    std::promise<bool> promises[THREADS_NUMBER];
    std::future<bool> futures[THREADS_NUMBER];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        futures[i] = promises[i].get_future();
    std::thread threads[THREADS_NUMBER];

    std::vector<int> divisiors[THREADS_NUMBER];
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
        divisiors[i % THREADS_NUMBER].push_back(i);

    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS_NUMBER; i++) 
        threads[i] = std::thread{ [&]() { f(n, divisiors[i], promises[i]); }};

    bool isPrime = true;
    for(auto & f : futures) {
        bool out = f.get();
        isPrime = out && isPrime;
    }

    for (auto& t : threads)
        t.join();

    if(isPrime) std::cout << "PRIME" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "NOT PRIME" << std::endl;

}
```

I compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -lpthread` on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue occurs with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < THREADS_NUMBER; i++) 
    threads[i] = std::thread{ [&]() { f(n, divisiors[i], promises[i]); }};
```

The `[&]` captures all variables by reference. This includes `promises` and `i`.  However, the code inside the lambda is not yet executed.  It doesn't run until the operating system has set up the thread and so on.   By the time the thread begins execution, the main thread's `for` loop has finished, and the variable `i` has ended its lifetime.

But then the thread executes `promises[i]`, where both of those are reference-captures. It looks up the references for both `promises` and `i` in order to do this. `promises` is fine, but `i` refers to a variable that no longer exists.  Probably the segfault is due to `i` having a garbage value as a result of this lookup and then accessing out of bounds.

Even hoisting `int i;` out of the loop doesn't fix the problem; then the reference in the lambda does find `i`, but it has the final value after completing the loop of `THREADS_NUMBER`, which is out of bounds for the `promises` array.

To fix the problem, capture `i` by value:

```
threads[i] = std::thread{ [&,i]() { f(n, divisiors[i], promises[i]); }};
```

Then each lambda uses the value of `i` as it was when the lambda was created.

---

Note: I think it is OK for a `std::thread` to have a temporary lambda as constructor parameter, but not sure about that either. The standard does seem to say that the thread constructor copies the functor provided.  But all the cppreference examples I searched had a named lambda created first, and then that name given as the constructor parameter to `std::thread`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I would never find out it by myself (in fact I spend about 8 hours on that issue and no effects) - I've never used lambdas in c++, but they looked quite straight-forward for me so I haven't thought that it could be an issue :) Thank's again!

Comment: @sadida it took me a long time to figure out what was happening too!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is due to this line: `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) futures[i] = promises[i].get_future();` - if `n>THREADS_NUMBER` then it try to read/write from/to promises/futures that was not allocated.

Comment: for me it still gives the segfault even when `n == THREADS_NUMBER`

Comment: yes, i just noticed this too. @M.M i think your answer below regarding the `i` capture by reference is solving the core issue!